# Как создать таблицу в sqlite с датой, которая ссылается на юзера?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

Нужно что бы создавалась таблица с пользователями и к каждого пользователя записывалась дата и время

пробовал так, не получается(

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS STAFF( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
, FIO TEXT NOT NULL, 
staff_id INTEGER);''')
# вставляем данные сотрудника
sqlite_insert_with_name = """INSERT INTO 'STAFF'
                  ('FIO', 'staff_id')
                  VALUES (?,?);"""

name_tuple = (name,)
cur.execute(sqlite_insert_with_name, name_tuple)
conn.commit()
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS STAFF_DATE( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY FIO
, DATE timestamp NOT NULL
, staff_id INTEGER
, FOREIGN KEY(staff_id) REFERENCES STAFF(id));''')

sqlite_insert_with_data = """INSERT INTO 'STAFF_DATE'
                  ('DATE', id)
                  VALUES (?,?);"""
data_tuple = (f"{time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time.localtime())}",)
cur.execute(sqlite_insert_with_data, data_tuple)
conn.commit()
cur.close()
```

Comment: Можно в поле `DATE timestamp NOT NULL` дописать значение по умолчанию, что примет функцию датывремени, типа https://stackoverflow.com/a/2939056/5909792

Comment: Дело в том что и таблица вторая с датой не создаётся..